# where clause with = sign matches multiple records while expected just one record

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a simple inline view that contains 2 columns.

> `-----------------`
>   `rn    |  val`
>   `-----------------`
>   `0     |   A`
>   `...   |   ...`
>   `25    |   Z`

I am trying to select a `val` by matching the `rn` randomly by using the `dbms_random.value()` method as in

```
    with d (rn, val) as 
    (
     select level-1, chr(64+level) from dual connect by level <= 26
    )
    select * from d 
    where rn = floor(dbms_random.value()*25) 
    ;
```

My expectation is it should return one row only without failing. 
  But now and then I get **multiple rows returned or no rows at all**.

on the other hand,

```
>>select floor(dbms_random.value()*25) from dual connect by level <1000
```

returns a whole number for each row and I failed to see any abnormality.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the random value is recalculated for each row.  So, you might get two random values that match the value -- or go through all the values and never get a hit.

One way to get around this is:

```
select d.*
from (select d.*
      from d 
      order by dbms_random.value()
     ) d
where rownum = 1;
```

There are more efficient ways to calculate a random number, but this is intended to be a simple modification to your existing query.

You also might want to ask another question.  This question starts with a description of a table that is not used, and then the question is about a query that doesn't use the table.  Ask *another* question, describing the table and the real problem you are having -- along with sample data and desired results.